# How to call a function that is located in a different file to set $_SESSION variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a registration and login app as a project. I'm having some issues with the registration process. I created a file called 'formProcess.php' that accepts input from a user and stores it in a database (which works) and calls another file to set the Session variables ('loginProcess.php'), then redirects the user to a dashboard ('dashboard.php') if it all checks out. I think I have everything working correctly except for setting the session variables; the users information is being stored in the DB and the user is being redirected to the dashboard, but the session variables within the dashboard page are not working.
 I'm very new to PHP so I'm sure the problem is very obvious, but I've been staring at this issue for hours now and I can't find the problem.

I think it has something to do with how I'm using the header function, but I'm not sure. I tried wrapping the header function in a if(isset()) but then the user never made it to the dashboard.Which (I think) isolates the problem, that the formProcess and loginProcess files are not linking correctly.

Here is a snip from the formProcess.php file. I'm calling the 'longinProcess' file in the `if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))` statement.

```php
//calls function to see if there is already a student in the system with the same email
require_once "checkProcess.php";
$check = checkStudents($email);
// if the the function returns true then the studnet is not in the system already
if($check){
  $sql= "INSERT INTO students (studentFirstName, studentLastName, studentEmail, studentPhone, studentGender, studentTextArea, studentAddress, studentAddress2, studentCity, studentState, studentPostCode, studentPassword)
   VALUES('{$firstName}','{$lastName}','{$email}','{$phone}','{$gender}','{$notes}','{$streetAddress}','{$streetAddress2}','{$city}','{$state}','{$postCode}','{$password}')";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    require_once "loginProcess.php"; //THIS IS NOT WORKING
    loginSession($email,$password);

      header('Location: url to dashboard.not sure if I want to share the real url with the world.');
      // creating a session

      //Creating Session variables
    //sending user to dashboard
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
```

Here is all of the loginProcess.php file

```php
<? session_start();


function loginSession($userEmail, $userPassword){
      include 'config.php';
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

          if($row["studentEmail"] == $email && $row['studentPassword'] == $password){

            $_SESSION["id"]= $row["id"];
            $_SESSION["firstName"] = $row["studentFirstName"];
            $_SESSION["lasName"] = $row["studentLastName"];
            $_SESSION["email"] = $row["studentEmail"];
            $_SESSION["phone"] = $row["studentPhone"];
            $_SESSION["gender"] = $row["studentGender"];
            $_SESSION["notes"] = $row["studentTextArea"];
            $_SESSION["streetAddress"] = $row["streetAddress"];
            $_SESSION["streetAddress2"] = $row["streetAddress2"];
            $_SESSION["city"] = $row["studentCity"];
            $_SESSION["state"] = $row["studentstate"];
            $_SESSION["postCode"] = $row["studentPostCode"];
            $_SESSION["password"] = $row["studentPassword"];
        }
      }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

So, currently the session variables are not being set and I'm not sure what the issue is. Also, I have `<? session_start();?>` on the top of both files.

PS. I know I need to hash the password, that is the next step. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if it is okay to use <? as opening php tag

Comment: @fmsthird depends if the option is enabled or not. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Philip, one little thing to make this more efficient, instead of `SELECT * FROM students` and then looping through all rows to find the right one, instead learn how to use a `WHERE` clause in the SQL to restrict the result and only get a single result back

Comment: Anyway I'm going to guess that your issue is this: `&& $row['studentPassword'] == $password` - `$password` appears to be your database password. Did you mean to use `$userPassword` here instead?

Comment: Hey @ADyson, great catch! I just fixed that bug, but somehting else seems to be wrong because the session variable is still not displaying on the dashboard.php page. Here is the excerpt from the file. I'm not concatenating wrong am I?  `echo '<h1 id=dashHeader> Welcome'.$_SESSION["firstName"].'!</h1>';`

Comment: Yes your concatenation looks fine. Did you put session_start() in that file too? It needs to be at the top of every file where you want to access the session. Might make sense to put it in your common header or config file, if you include that into every script, then you know it's always there.

Comment: P.S. I just noticed that `$row["studentEmail"] == $email` is also wrong, should be using `$userEmail`. Did you fix that too?

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, that was the problem (email)!  Thank you. Also, to refer back to your previous suggestion about making it more efficient by using the WHERE clause, is it more efficient because SQL is faster than PHP? If I use the WHERE clase than I'm essentially asking SQL to loop through the data instead of PHP, right?

Comment: It's more efficient yes because SQL can filter the data much faster than you can by looping in PHP (especially once you get a large number of users). SQL also doesn't loop, SQL queries are set-based operations, the implementation is different. Also if you only return one row then there's less data being transferred between SQL and PHP which would improve performance. On a fast PC with a low number of users you won't notice any difference but I pointed it out as a general principle to take note of in all queries of this kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking **`$row['studentPassword']`** against your database password.
I should hope they are different so the session variables are not being set.
I believe it's  **`$row['studentPassword'] == $userPassword`** is what your require.

Comment: Actually same with email. ==  $userEmail

Answer (score 2):

You can make a separate file and include that at the top of every php file.For example header.php and put `session_start`

```
<?php session_start();?>
```

After including this file on top of every PHP page, remove the `session_start` if that coming on any of the files after require_once `header.php`.

> Good practive to use PDO connection instead of mysqli to prevent SQL injection in applicatoin.

It seems that you are looping through all the available user , you can avoid that and direct use

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE `studentEmail`='$userEmail'"
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($row['studentPassword'] == $password){// Here you can match the password
            /*
                Assign Session
            */
        }
     }
 }else{
    echo "0 results";
 }
```

Now to check the session using `print_r($_SESSION)` just after `loginSession($email,$password);`.

You have to include the `header.php` only once in `formProcess.php' at the top.You don't need that in`loginProcess.php`

Comment: good point about SQL injection, but your suggestion to "use PDO connection instead of mysqli to prevent SQL injection" is not correct. mysqli can also be used to prevent injection - it supports parameterised queries in a very similar way to PDO. There's no need to completely switch libraries in order to protect against that.

Comment: @ADyson gotcha..!!

Comment: No problem - you can read it here in fact: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php . P.S. It would make sense to edit your answer to change your statement slightly :-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @RakeshJakhar. I will start making a header.php file from now on.